# iOS Share extension close action

Tags: ios, swift, share

I've encountered some strange behavior of the share extension - when sharing a text, perform small drag action and let it bounce back up - it closes(not doing so with images). I've tried it with plenty of other apps - Twitter, slack - same there. Then I've tried it with the system mail application and noticed that it asks to save the draft. So apparently, there is a way to intercept this action somehow. Any ideas on how to do that? (existing completerequest or cancelrequest are not called in the code).
Also I've tried to avoid this by presenting the extension in a fullscreen mode, using
NSExtensionActionWantsFullScreenPresentation(I know that it is intended to work with action extensions, but I found that it worked for someone with sharing extension).
But it doesn't work for the sharing extensions anymore. And once again, we can see applications that run their share extensions in a fullscreen.

UPD:
isModalInPresentation = true helped to avoid dismissal by drag.
But still nothing regarding showing the extension in a fullscreen mode.

Comment: Can you share some of your code?

Comment: @luca_999 it happens on any ''stage of it'' - empty extension or fully customized with heavy navigation and so on